# Meaning of "avere a che fare" in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I have read the following sentence:

> La metà della popolazione ha a che fare con la povertà.

I know "avere a che fare" has 2 distinct meanings:

- to have sth to do (= to be related to)
- to deal with

However, I am not sure if the sentence above means that half of the population deals with poverty in its everyday life (e.g., seeing beggars in the street, seeing people sleeping under viaducts, etc) or that half of the population is poor. Could someone please make it clear?

Comment: It's a lot more likely that the intended meaning is the second one, but it is context dependent, so it would be better if you could give some of the surrounding sentences.

Comment: I also agree that the meaning could be the second one you wrote, but more than _half of the population is poor_ I think that the meaning is that half the population have to deal with the fact that they are becoming poor or at risk of becoming poor.

Comment: As an Italian, I wouldn't be sure of the meaning of this sentence without knowing its context. It literally just says that half the population is in some relation with poverty.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the context because the sentence was provided as it is in an Italian language learning tool. Anyway, what I wanted to know was the possible interpretations and the most usual one and you guys have already discussed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It means that half of the population deals with poverty in everyday life.
You could also translate it with

> Half of the population is affected by poverty